# share seekbar progress between android activities

Tags: android, android-activity, sharing

How can I share the seekbar progress from my main activity to another activity?

Here is my seekbar code:

```
SeekBar seekbarChargeStart;


seekbarChargeStart = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar_charge_start);


seekbarChargeStart.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
                        int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                    chargeStart.setText("Charge start is "
                            + progress);

                }

                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }

                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }
            });
```

If the seekbar is a void type how can you utilize this information anywhere else such as in another activity all together?

I have tried using the getProgress() but keep getting a null exception. I am calling the getProgress() in an activitiy other than main (which is the one that has the seekbar)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Make the seekbarChargeStart static and you can get it via class access (Activity.seekbarChargeStart)

Comment: It says "Return type for this method is missing" when i change void to static.